# Markov chain getting stuck due to insufficient data samples

Tags: markov-chain

There is a lot of theory on Markov models and output generation, but I cannot locate any information on models getting stuck.

I'm trying to create a model of a data set using a Markov model. The data can look like this "abc abb acc baa bcc...", and I want to make an n-gram model. Accordingly, I sample the data set at random, so I get a model like this (example of 2-gram model):

- abc abb -> acc with probability p1
- acc baa -> bcc with probability p2
- ...

The problem occurs, when I try to generate an output from the model. Say I initiate the model like this:

- First: abc abb => acc, so the output is now "abc abb acc"
- Second (taking the last two words of the output): abb acc => ???

The model gets stuck, because the data set is not complete, and therefore does not cover every possible combination. When making the mode, the sample "abb acc" was never reached, and thus the output cannot be determined.

I initially asked the question on the C.S. forum site ([link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17791/markov-chain-getting-stuck-due-to-insufficient-data-samples)), and was advised to ask it here. From the C.S. site, smoothing functions like the Laplace smoothing and Good-Turing smoothing were suggested. Is that the best way to go, or does other methods exist?

Comment: The question from CS got [migrated here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/markov-chain-getting-stuck-due-to-insufficient-data-samples), flagging to close as duplicate.